# Twig variable with includes

Tags: php, symfony, variables, include

I'm trying to save SVG markup as a variable to pass into an include.
Something like this:

```
{% set var1 = {
  'svg': include './test-image.svg',
  'other_var': 'test string'
} %}

{% include './module.twig' with var1 %}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but what you cannot do is to use is the

```
include './test-image.svg',
```